# Grab htmls results from a php statement?

Tags: php

I was wonder if there was a way to take the html results that was created from a php script and take that html code generated and put it inside another php script?

The problem I'm having is that I'm working inside a huge php script and I always have errors when I'm working inside it. I want to make additions to the code, but it never works. Files aren't opening. However, when I work outside it and within the same folder, my code works.

So I'm thinking if there's an "Iframe" for php code or maybe I should use an iframe instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use include or require to include the code from the other script?

1. Create a function myFunction to output whatever html you want.
2. Put that code in a file whatever.php
3. Call include('whatever.php') from your other PHP file
4. Call myFunction() and your html will be outputted.

Comment: the problem is that my code conflicts with the php script's code for a reason I do not understand. I did an include statement, but the include statement grabs the code, not the result generated from my php code.

Comment: You have to do more then use the include.  Wrap your code in a function... like `function myFunction() { echo "<p>Hi there</p>" }`.  Then call that function `myFunction();` from the PHP file with the include.